# Weird hierarchical select requirement for Drupal

Tags: drupal, cck, taxonomy

Anybody know of a module or other way to do a hierarchical select in Drupal that first pulls in a taxonomy vocabulary from which you select and then based on your taxonomy selection limits a CCK related node field to a specific content type.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no module that does that. A node reference field does allow you to specify a view as its source, but unfortunately, you cannot pass a dynamic argument to that view.

If you can figure out a way to take the selected taxonomy term and pass it to the view as an argument to filter the results by, you're done...

There is a start for something similar on http://drupal.org/node/473670, but that code fetches the dynamic argument on the PHP level from a GET variable. The behavior you describe should work on the Javascript level, because your argument is a variable selected on the form by the user.